# C++, Can I use default constructor in builder pattern? Please check my problem and my solution

Tags: c++, design-patterns, builder-pattern

```
class Email
{
public:
  //Email(){} //If I added this, this problem is resolved. But I am not sure this is good solution.
  Email(EmailBuilder builder){
     ...
  }

  public class EmailBuilder {
     EmailBuilder() {...};
     EmailBuilder SetAddress(...) {...};
     EmailBuilder SetSubject(...) {...};
     EmailBuilder SetBody(...) {...};
     Email Build() {...};
  }
};  

class EmailSender
    {
    public:
       ...
       SendEmail(const Email& mail)
       {
           mEmail = mail;           }
    private:
       Email mEmail; //error : emailsender.h(8): error C2512: 'Email': no appropriate default constructor available
    }


    int main()
    {
        Email mail = new Email.Builder
                            .SetAddress("me@mail.com")
                            .SetSubject("C++ builders")
                            .SetBody("I like this API, don't you?")
                            .Build();
        ...
        EmailSender emailSender;
        ...
        emailSender.SendEmail(mail);
        ...
    }
```

It is just pseudocode.

I want to copy parameter(=mail) to local object(=mEmail).

But I cannot it.

If I added default constructor(Email(){}), this problem is resolved. But I am not sure this is good solution.

Could you give me more good solution?

Comment: What errors do you get? What is `Aobject`? What members does it contain? Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] (with emphasis on the *minimal* part), and a copy-paste (as text!) of the full and complete errors you get with comments in the code where you get them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `EmailSender` class contains an `Email` object named `mEmail`. This `mEmail` object of course needs to be initialized (constructed).

The problem is that `mEmail` needs to be constructed *before* the body of the `EmailSender` constructor runs, and the compiler can only default-construct it using the non-existent default constructor, leading to your error.

The solution is to explicitly initialize (construct) `mEmail` in the `EmailSender` *constructor initializer list*:

```
EmailSender(Email const& email)
    : mEmail{ email }  // Initialize (construct) using the copy-constructor
{
    // Empty body
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But If EmailSender class is singleton, I think your solution is not available.

EmailSender() : mEmail( make empty Email object ) 

How about this?

It is working. But I am not sure whether it is reasonable code.

Please let me know your opinion.

Comment: @sensolama Then I sense a problem in your *design*. If `EmailSender` should be a singleton that can be used to send multiple different emails, then it shouldn't really have its own `mEmail` member object. Instead it should have a `Send` function that takes a (reference) to an `Email` object.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, currently I use "struct Email { ... };" to resolve simply this problem. (like C data structure). But I hope I want to resolve this issue using C++ language with good design.